# How to have a compute field's value in domain action of a smart-button

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

In my model i've a compute field that give the ID of the active contract of this user :

```
id_ultimo_contratto = fields.Integer(compute="_compute_last_contratto", store=True)
```

this is the function that i use  to calculate the id (and it's correct i've the right value) :

```
@api.multi
@api.depends()
def _compute_last_contratto(self):
    id_utenza=self.id
    contratto_attivo = ''   
    for AttivitaSvoltaEE in self.env['utilitypower.attivitasvolta_ee'].search([('id_utenza_ee','=',id_utenza)]):
        id_attivita = AttivitaSvoltaEE.id
        for Contratto in self.env['utilitypower.contratti_ee'].search([('attivitasvolte_ids','=',id_attivita)]):
            if Contratto.stato==1:
               #find it :
               id_contratto_attivo = Contratto.id
               id_ultima_attivita = id_attivita
               contratto_attivo=Contratto.nome_contratto               
    for UtenzeEE in self:
        UtenzeEE.last_contratto = contratto_attivo
        UtenzeEE.id_ultimo_contratto = id_contratto_attivo
        UtenzeEE.id_ultima_attivita = id_ultima_attivita
```

I use this id in a smart-button and i want to open the view of the contract with an action linked at the smart-button :

```
<button class="oe_stat_button" 
         icon = "fa-file-text-o" 
         type = "action" 
         name="action_view_contrattoattivo_ee" 
         options="{}"> 
            <span><field name="id_ultimo_contratto"/></span> 
</button>
```

The problem is that i can't understand how to pass the id_ultimocontratto field_value in the domain/context of the action:

```
<act_window id="action_view_contrattoattivo_ee" 
            name="Contratto Attivo"
            res_model="utilitypower.contratti_ee"
            view_type="tree,form"
            view_mode="tree"
            domain="[]"
/>
```

How do I pass the calculated field into the domain? and how i can refer to the id (odoo) of the final model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below button code

```
<button class="oe_stat_button" 
     icon = "fa-file-text-o" 
     type = "object" 
     name="action_view_contrattoattivo_ee" 
     options="{}"> 
        <span><field name="id_ultimo_contratto"/></span>
```

in the py file write below code

```
      @api.multi
      def action_view_contrattoattivo_ee(self):

        action = self.env.ref('module_name.action_view_contrattoattivo_ee')
        result = action.read()[0]
        result['domain'] = domain
        return result
```

module_name: It should be the module in which you have written the action.
  domain: domain you want to specify.

You can give the integer field non store as below:

```
id_ultimo_contratto = fields.Integer(compute="_compute_last_contratto")

@api.multi
def _compute_last_contratto(self):
    id_utenza=self.id
    contratto_attivo = ''   
    for AttivitaSvoltaEE in self.env['utilitypower.attivitasvolta_ee'].search([('id_utenza_ee','=',id_utenza)]):
        id_attivita = AttivitaSvoltaEE.id
        for Contratto in self.env['utilitypower.contratti_ee'].search([('attivitasvolte_ids','=',id_attivita)]):
            if Contratto.stato==1:
               #find it :
               id_contratto_attivo = Contratto.id
               id_ultima_attivita = id_attivita
               contratto_attivo=Contratto.nome_contratto               
    for UtenzeEE in self:
        UtenzeEE.last_contratto = contratto_attivo
        UtenzeEE.id_ultimo_contratto = id_contratto_attivo
        UtenzeEE.id_ultima_attivita = id_ultima_attivita
```

Please be informed that, if you are calling any action through button, you have to write the code as below

```
<button class="oe_stat_button" 
     icon = "fa-file-text-o" 
     type = "action" 
     name="%(action_view_contrattoattivo_ee)d" 
     options="{}"> 
        <span><field name="id_ultimo_contratto"/></span>
```

Comment: Hi Anitha and thanks for your reply, but I have to ask you further clarifications because I don't understand. I realized that with the object type button I can declare a function and from there pass the domain to the action I created.
But I don't know how to write this domain because:
I have the calculated field id_ultimo_contratto and I have to connect it with the id of the module utilitypower.contratti_ee (the id is decided by odoo, I don't declare it in the module) .. it should be something like this [('Utilitypower.contratti_ee.id', '=', last_contact_id)]

Comment: Also I don't understand if the action has to remain on the utilities_ee module (which is where the smart button is) or if it has to be on the contract_ee module (which is the module I have to show when I click the button).

Comment: Basically I know that i have this problem: 1- when I have to declare an action I never know if it should be in the caller's model or in the receiver model; 2 - if I have to enter something other than active_id in the domain or the id I create automatically to identify the record in the table instead of a field I created, I don't know how to referece at it

Comment: Hi , If you are writing an object type button then you have to define the function, that I have mentioned in my reply, is in the model where you have written the button code. That is if you are defined a button in the model of sale order to see sale order lines , then you have to write the function in sale order model. Your domain will be [('id',=, id_ultimo_contratto)].

Comment: Please be informed that the function must be written in the source model where you have defined he button code. Not in the model you have see as a result.

Comment: If you have the id of the resultant model you want to see, then you can compare with id field using domain, just as in my first comment